# Swift: Player Jump Animation

Tags: swift, animation

I'm trying to get my player to play the jump animation when the touch begins. The player is in his own swift file and I have the GameScene.swift call his file so everything that deals with his movement is in player.swift file. Any help would be awesome!

```
import SpriteKit




struct ColliderType {
static let PLAYER: UInt32 = 0
static let GROUND: UInt32 = 1
static let ROCKET_AND_COLLECTABLES: UInt32 = 2


}



class Player: SKSpriteNode {

private var textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
private var playerAnimation = [SKTexture]()
private var animatePlayerAction = SKAction()
let jumpAnimation1 = [SKTexture]()
let jumpAnimation2 = [SKTexture]()

var jumpAnimation = SKAction ()

func initializePlayer() {
    name = "Player"

    for i in 1...7 {
        let name = "Player \(i)"
        playerAnimation.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))



    }


    animatePlayerAction = SKAction.animate(with: playerAnimation,    

timePerFrame: 0.08, resize: true, restore: false)

    //Animate the player forever.
    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(animatePlayerAction))


    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 
self.size.width-60, height: self.size.height-80))
    physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    //Restitution is Boucniess 
    physicsBody?.restitution  = 0
    physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.PLAYER
    physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.GROUND
    physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =                                        

ColliderType.ROCKET_AND_COLLECTABLES

}




func move (){
    self.position.x += 10
}

func reversePlayer() {
    physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 300))

    playerNode?.removeAction(forKey:"animate")           playerNode?.run(attackAnimation,completion:{
        self.playerNode?.run(self.animation,withKey: "animate")
}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the part where you set textures, create and run the action with the following code snippet. It works perfectly for me and is the simplest way to do it.

```
let hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero")
hero.size = CGSize(width: 45, height: 125)
let f1 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "h1")
let f2 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "h2")
let f3 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "h3")
let frames: [SKTexture] = [f1, f2, f3]   
let hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "h1")
let animation = SKAction.animate(with: frames, timePerFrame: 0.1)
hero.run(SKAction.repeatForever(animation))
```

Also, it is possible that your animation action cannot be accessed as it is in another file. Declare the player and animations globally i.e. outside of any class or function. Hope it works for you!